# Probability of $j$ inversions in an array

Tags: probability

I have $n$ elements which are permutation of $\{1,2,...,n\}$, , then what is the probability of having $j$ inversions in the result.

Comment: How do you define an inversion in a context in which the elements aren't distinct?

Comment: From Wikipedia definition of Inversion: If $i < j$ and $A(i) > A(j)$, then the pair $(i, j)$ is called an inversion of $A$. If $A(i) = A(j)$ then this is not an inversion by this definition.

Comment: See formulas to compute number of permutations with $k$ inversions in [OEIS A008302](https://oeis.org/A008302). Also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372991/number-of-n-element-permutations-with-exactly-k-inversions) on Stack Overflow.